# When navigating to other page keep showing the navtabs

Tags: angular6, angular7, ionic4

I am migrating my application from ionic 3 to ionic 4 and I am wondering how to keep showing the navtabs when navigating between pages. When I do this:

`[routerLink]="'/offers/'" routerDirection="forward"`

The tabs disappear, what do I have to do when I almost always want to show the navtabs?

Define the routes in `tabs.router.module.ts` or in the pages?

Hope somebody could help me out on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this is doing it for me. So basically yes, define the routes in your router's routing module.

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';
import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    entryComponents: [],
    imports: [
        IonicModule.forRoot(),
        AppRoutingModule,
    ],
    providers: [
        { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy },
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'start/tabs', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'start', loadChildren: './pages/tabs/tabs.module#TabsModule' },
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

**tabs.module.ts**

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { PageAPageModule } from '../pageA/PageA.module';
import { PageBPageModule } from '../pageB/PageB.module';

import { TabsPage } from './tabs.page';
import { TabsPageRoutingModule } from './tabs.page-routing.module';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        IonicModule,
        PageAPageModule,
        PageBPageModule,
        TabsPageRoutingModule,
    ],
    declarations: [
        TabsPage,
    ],
})
export class TabsModule {
}
```

**tabs.page-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { PageAPage } from '../pageA/pageA.page';
import { TabsPage } from './tabs.page';

const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'tabs',
        component: TabsPage,
        children: [
            {
                path: 'pageA',
                children: [
                    { path: '', component: PageAPage },
                    { path: 'subPageA1', loadChildren: '../subPageA1/subPageA1.module#SubPageA1PageModule' },
                    { path: 'subPageA2', loadChildren: '../subPageA2/subPageA2.module#SubPageA2PageModule' },
                ],
            },
            {
                path: 'pageB',
                children: [
                    { path: '', loadChildren: '../pageB/pageB.module#PageBPageModule' },
                    { path: ':id', loadChildren: '../pageB-detail/pageB-detail.module#PageBDetailModule' },
                ],
            },
            {
                path: 'pageX',
                ...
            },
            {
                path: '', redirectTo: '/start/tabs/pageA', pathMatch: 'full',
            },
        ],
    },
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class TabsPageRoutingModule {
}
```

**tabs.page.html**

```
<ion-tabs>
    <ion-tab-bar color="dark" slot="bottom">
        <ion-tab-button tab="pageA">
            <ion-icon name="calendar"></ion-icon>
            <ion-label>pageA</ion-label>
        </ion-tab-button>

        <ion-tab-button tab="pageB">
            <ion-icon name="contacts"></ion-icon>
            <ion-label>pageB</ion-label>
        </ion-tab-button>

        <ion-tab-button tab="pageX">
            <ion-icon name="contacts"></ion-icon>
            <ion-label>pageX</ion-label>
        </ion-tab-button>
    </ion-tab-bar>
</ion-tabs>
```

**app.component.html**

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-menu-toggle auto-hide="false">
        <ion-item routerLink="/start/tabs/pageA">
            <ion-icon slot="start" name="person"></ion-icon>
            <ion-label>pageA</ion-label>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-menu-toggle>

    <ion-menu-toggle auto-hide="false">
        <ion-item routerLink="/start/tabs/pageA/subPageA1">
            <ion-icon slot="start" name="person"></ion-icon>
            <ion-label>subPageA1</ion-label>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-menu-toggle>

    <ion-menu-toggle auto-hide="false">
        <ion-item routerLink="/start/tabs/pageB">
            <ion-icon slot="start" name="person"></ion-icon>
            <ion-label>pageB</ion-label>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-menu-toggle>

    <ion-menu-toggle auto-hide="false">
        <ion-item routerLink="/start/tabs/pageX">
            <ion-icon slot="start" name="person"></ion-icon>
            <ion-label>pageX</ion-label>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-menu-toggle>
</ion-list>
```

Comment: Looks like a solid solution. Thanks for the answer will look into it later today :) !